# Disable submit button after click and keep POST/REDIRECT/GET working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I use the POST/REDIRECT/GET trick to prevent refresh-resend of forms.
Now I would like to disable a form submit button (after click) that should not be clicked twice.
Although I tried all javascript examples I found, they all conflict with POST/REDIRECT/GET.
In most cases it doesn't even submit but just redirects to itself.
Any solution ? Thanks for your help.

Something I've tried and conflicts is this example:

the script first runs headers.php with this in:

```
if (isset($_POST['start-diff-scan']))
{
    $_SESSION['SCAN_START'] = true;

    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
    header('Location: '.APP_URL.'scan.php');
    exit;
}
```

and then scan.php with this form:

```
<form name="start-diff-scan" id="start-diff-scan" method="post">
    <button
        name="start-scan"
        id="start-scan"
        value=""
        class="start-scan btn btn-primary"
        type="submit"
        method="post">
        Start New Scan
    </button>
</form>
```

and works fine. but the js trick conflicts this. I added the js code at the very end of scan.php

```
<script>
$('#start-diff-scan').submit(function()
{
    $('#start-scan').prop('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

What happens is it only redirects to the same page (scan.php) without executing anything.
Thanks for all yoru answers and help so far this is great.
Any ideas appreciated thanks very much

Comment: Sounds like there's a server-side issue, so you may want to see what's happening there.

Comment: I do not think once it runs without a problem so far without what I am trying here...

Comment: And what happens on the server when you *are* doing this?

Comment: nothing gets executed, it just redirects to the same page

Comment: Possibly suggesting that `if (isset($_POST['start-scan']))` is evaluating to `false`? If that is the case, listening for the `submit` event of the form, rather than the `click` event of the button, may fix it. Also you said in another comment that you'd changed the `name` and `id` attributes of some elements - could you update the question to reflect that?

Comment: it doesn't go through headers.php at all, I tested adding `echo 1; exit;` right after `if (isset($_POST...` and it didn't exit; I will edit my post in a moment with the latest version I tryed thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent it this way, since it's user-side scripting, and people can easily delete this code, before sending the form. Even you disable the button. Make checks in your server-side script, whether the request is already inserted, so you will display them either an error, or get them back to the page

Comment: I agree, and thanks for the answer.. although I will work on how to stop it using php, I would also like it disabled client side ...

Answer (score 1):

`$('#start-scan').attr("disabled", true);`

Should work

Comment: It's a property, should be `.prop()`, not `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the "disable" method is messing up your code and all else fails :

You can try to overlay the button with a "loader gif" making it not clickable.

```
$('#start-scan').click(function()
{
    $('#start-scan').before('<div>LOADING</div>'); //Set the loading overlay width, height and background-color
});
```

Comment: Remember: Once the page is redirected the javascript will also be refreshed, this will enable the button again.

Comment: I do want the button released after scan is complete, but I would not like to start more than one `RecursiveIteratorIterator` on 20000 files at the same moment just by accident :) In any case, so far when scan completes you get redirected back to the same page. I would just like to disable the button while waiting.

Comment: Cool. And are you using Ajax? or a form submit? If you have any errors please let us see.

Comment: not using ajax, please check I edited the post. I also see no errors

Comment: What is the ID of the <form> ? Try to give the button and the form separate names.

Comment: I jsut did with various changes to names and ids on the form and button and it jsut redirects to the same page without executing what the button should do. Also if I try to refresh after that, I get the browser "resend" message.

Comment: If you pressed refresh and asked for "resend" then your redirect didn't work. It's a bit difficult to figure out what is wrong with what you are explaining and the answers you got, everything seems fine.

Comment: yes and tested it on a plain single file also with same results I dunno. the server is linux nothing to do with xampp etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is setting the disabled when the person clicks causes the button to be disabled and the click action does not fire off.

Add a setTimeout to delay setting the disabled property.

Other option is to hide the button and replace it with text that says submitting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#start-scan').attr('disabled', true);
```

or use

```
.prop("disabled", true)

$('#start-scan').prop("disabled", true)
```

Comment: same thing happens I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this in the form:

```
onClick="this.disabled=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

try `prop()`

```
$('#start-scan').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: are you calling the $.get in same button click.. can u post that ..where you are calling the $.get

Comment: jsut a moment I will edit my post check it in a moment thanks